# Checking if the game has ended ot not

Tags: python

```
players = [{'name': 'Player 1', 'score': 23, 'stayed': False, 'at_14': True, 'bust': True},
           {'name': 'Player 2', 'score': 17, 'stayed': True, 'at_14': True, 'bust': False},
           {'name': 'Player 3', 'score': 19, 'stayed': True, 'at_14': True, 'bust': False},
           {'name': 'Player 4', 'score': 19, 'stayed': True, 'at_14': True, 'bust': False}]
def end_of_game(players):
```

so this is a game where after every round, I need to call the function to check if the game has ended or not. If any player has "stayed, is False and "bust" is also False, the code must return "False". If "stayed" is False and "bust" is True or vice versa, the code will pass to the next step. Anyone knows how can I do this?

Comment: Please post the solution(s) you tried

Comment: In your function, write a loop to go through players array and check each player item for your conditions. The moment you find an item doesn't adhere to ur conditions, break the loop and return false. If you don't find any disqualifying elements after going through all players, return true outside the loop.

Comment: Doesn't seem complicated. If you coded the rest of the game you should surely be able to code that function, wouldn't you? *What exactly* are you having a problem with here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do it very simple with:

`all(player["stayed"] or player["bust"] for player in players )`

This expression checks for every player if at least one of "stayed" or "bust" is True. If there is one player which both are False, the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function will return False.

Answer (score 0):

You have here a simple `list` with 4 items or players. Each list item contains a `dict`, so you can loop through the `list` as usual with a `for` loop and get the values from the dict by filtering for the key.

That could look like this:

```
def end_of_game(players):
    for player in players:
        if player['stayed'] or player['bust']:
            return True
    return False
```

A good way to learn this is by working with `json's` or just with `api responses`